# What is the equivalent of Serial.available() in pyserial?

Tags: python, serial-port

When I am trying to read multiple lines of serial data on an Arduino, I use the following idiom:

```
String message = "";
while (Serial.available()){
    message = message + serial.read()
}
```

In Arduino C, `Serial.available()` returns the number of bytes available to be read from the serial buffer (See [Docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available)). *What is the equivalent of `Serial.available()` in python?*

For example, if I need to read multiple lines of serial data I would expect to ues the following code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=0.050)
...
while ser.available():
    print ser.readline()
```

Comment: Please either describe what `Serial.available()` is or provide a link to its documentation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The property [`Serial.in_waiting`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting) returns "the number of bytes in the receive buffer".

This seems to be the equivalent of [`Serial.available()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available)'s description: "the number of bytes ... that's already arrived and stored in the serial receive buffer."

Try:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=0.050)
...
while ser.in_waiting:  # Or: while ser.inWaiting():
    print ser.readline()
```

For versions prior to pyserial 3.0, use `.inWaiting()`. To determine your pyserial version, do this:

```
import serial
print(serial.__version__)
```

Comment: In all the introductory tutorials for `pyserial`, I have never seen the command `ser.in_waiting`. Is there a reason it is avoided? `Serial.available()` is ubiquitous in Arduino C serial communications. Do python developers typically use another idiom to accomplish the same task?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'in_waiting'
root@raspberrypi:/home/wf# python3 --version
Python 3.4.2

Comment: @WolfgangFahl - if your version of `pyserial` is older than 3.0, try `.inWaiting()`.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl 3.4.2 is your **python** version number. The change from `inWaiting()` to `in_waiting` occured in **pyserial** version 3.0. The pyserial version number is not necessarily related to the python version number. Try `import serial ; print (serial.__version__)`.

Comment: I'm unsure why this doesn't have more upvotes - this worked well for me!

Answer (score 2):

I have written my code as below. Hope you can use it modify your code

```
import serial
import csv
import os
import time
import sys
import string
from threading import Timer

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    COUNT=0

    f=open("test.csv","w+");
    result = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    result_statement=("Dir","ACTUATOR_ON_OFF","MODE","DATE","TIME"," TRACKER DESIRED ANGLE"," TRACKER ACTUAL ANGLE")
    result.writerow(result_statement)
    f.close()
    while COUNT<=100:
    #while():
      time.sleep(60)
      ser=serial.Serial()
      ser.port=12
      ser.baudrate=9600
      ser.open()

      str=ser.read(150)
      # print "string are:\n",str
      print type(str)
      val=str.split(":")
      # print "value is:\n",val
      lines=str.split("\r\n")
     # print  "line statement are :\n",lines
      COUNT=COUNT+1
      print COUNT
      f=open("test.csv","a+");
      result = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
      wst=[]
      for line in lines[:-1]:
            parts=line.split(":")
            for p in parts[1:]:
                wst.append(p)


            #result = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
            #wst.append(parts[1:])

      print "wst:\n",wst
      result.writerow(wst)
      f.close()
f.close()
ser.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Ajit, but your code unfortunately doesn't address my issue. You simply expect 150 bytes of serial data to be available with `ser.read(150)` rather than checking to see how much (if any) is available. Some extra tips, a lot of this code can be improved to by more python-like (shorter, cleaner, faster, easier to read). Try using the `with` keyword in play of `f = open()`, `f.close()`, and `ser.close()`. Additionally, your `while COUNT<=100:` should be replaced with a `for i in xrange(100)` or `for i in xrange(1, 101)` if zero indexing is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem like so. The only drawback of this code is that when the first time I'm sending letter 'a', ser.inWaiting() will return 0. To remove this effect I added delay of 1 second before it. That seems to solve the problem.

In my case, ATmega16 sends back a string either 8 or 12bits. So, I will get the number of bits arriving to RPi with ser.inWaiting() and then I'll read that much data with ser.read(), combining them into ser.read(ser.inWaiting())

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import serial # version is 3.2.1

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', 9600)
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

led1 = 16
led2 = 18
button = 7

GPIO.setup(led1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Enter 'a' if you want to turn LED ON or 'b' "
                       + "to turn the LED OFF: ")
        if (choice == "a"):
            print "Sending command to turn LED ON"
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.HIGH)
            sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.LOW)
            #Send the actual data
            ser.write('a');
            #Receive what ATmega it send back
            sleep(1)
            received_data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            print "Received data: " + received_data

        elif (choice == "b"):
            print "Sending command to turn LED OFF"
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.HIGH)
            sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.LOW)
            #Send the actual data
            ser.write('b');
            #Receive what ATmega it sends back
            sleep(1)
            received_data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            print "Received data: " + received_data

        else:
            print "Invalid command"
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.HIGH)
            sleep(.3)
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.LOW)
            sleep(.3)
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.HIGH)
            sleep(.3)
            GPIO.output(led1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(led2, GPIO.LOW)
            #send invalid command
            ser.write(choice);
            #receive what ATmega sends back
            sleep(1)
            received_data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            print "Received data: " + received_data

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

A correct answer will depend on the version of Python - this has tripped me up for some time today. I suspect some of the comments were running on Raspberry Pi which is currently at Python 2.7.9 and similarly less-than-current pySerial.

So on a Pi you might use `ser.inWaiting()` which is similar to `Serial.available()` in Arduino C - both return the number of bytes in the receive buffer; for pySerial >= 3.0 you use `ser.in_waiting` (note this is an attribute not a function - http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting)

Incidentally, on a Pi (and presumably older Pythons/pySerials) `import serial ; print (serial.__version__)` results in an attribute error but works on newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ser.readline()` with `timeout=1`

Comment: Please elaborate more on what You code does and how it should be implemented

Answer (score -1):

When you initialize port and baud rate, you have to set timeout because without time out `ser.readline()` is not working.